# Accessing an array works with Brackets in Chrome but not in IE

Tags: javascript

In JavaScript I have something like this:

```
var abc = myXML.evaluateXPath("//XYZ/XYZ[@User='" + userName + "']");
```

Then few lines later I am accessing it its elements in a loop like this:

```
abc(i)
```

That one works in IE **but not** in Chrome, Chrome thinks it is a function call.
Now If I change it to

```
abc[i]
```

Then it works in Chrome **but not** in IE :)

What should I do?

Comment: What is `myXML`?  I can't find an `evaluateXPath` on MDN.

Comment: its XML stuff, I did a console.log on it, it returned an array

Comment: That doesn’t help us find a match for the evaluateXPath method.  myXML is an instance of what type of object?  It’s not a generic object or array, as neither of those has an evaluateXPath method.

Comment: Dunno what is under evaluateXPath's hood but its possible that it returns different results because IE does not support `document.evaluate` (XPath) method. There is workaround via ActiveXObject. Just check `typeof abc === "function"`

Answer (score -2):

why don't use a function for return the value?

```
getValueFromProperty = function(username) {

  return myXML.evaluateXPath("//XYZ/XYZ[@User='" + userName + "']");
}
```

Call it.

```
getValueFromProperty(i)
```